# PowerShell create App with client secret and API permissions

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

I'm trying to create an App in Azure with a client secret and API permissions.
I've used the AzureAD (Preview) module and MgGraph (Beta) but I'm getting stuck on different things on both.

The end goal is for the script to ask user creds to login to a tenancy and fully create the app with the correct permissions.

AzureAD

```
$myApp = New-AzureADApplication -DisplayName $appName

$startDate = Get-Date
$endDate = $startDate.AddYears(1)
$appSecret = New-AzureADApplicationPasswordCredential -ObjectId $myApp.ObjectId -CustomKeyIdentifier "Access" -StartDate $startDate -EndDate $endDate
```

Now I can't find a way to add permissions using the AzureAD module.

I also tried MgGraph but so far can only create the app

```
$myApp = New-MgBetaApplication -DisplayName $appName
```

I also did some research on the Az module which seems to be the easiest to setup the API permissions but not sure about the rest.

I can do all the steps but on different modules which is not great!

If someone could point the way or share some code would be amazing.

Cheers,

C

Answer (score 0):

You can run below script to create application with **client secret** and **API permissions** using Azure AD module:

```
Connect-AzureAD -TenantId <TenantID>

$appName="SriDemoApp"
$myApp = New-AzureADApplication -DisplayName $appName #Create Azure AD application

$startDate = Get-Date
$endDate = $startDate.AddYears(1)
New-AzureADApplicationPasswordCredential -ObjectId $myApp.ObjectId -CustomKeyIdentifier "Access" -StartDate $startDate -EndDate $endDate #Create client secret

$Graph = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.RequiredResourceAccess"
$Graph.ResourceAppId = "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000" #Microsoft Graph resource

$AppUserReadAll = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.ResourceAccess" -ArgumentList "df021288-bdef-4463-88db-98f22de89214","Role" #Application permission(User.Read.All)
$DelUserRead = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.ResourceAccess" -ArgumentList "e1fe6dd8-ba31-4d61-89e7-88639da4683d","Scope"  #Delegated permission(User.Read)
$Graph.ResourceAccess = $AppUserReadAll, $DelUserRead

#Add API permissions   
Set-AzureADApplication -ObjectId $myApp.ObjectId -RequiredResourceAccess $Graph
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I checked the same in Portal, new application named **`SriDemoApp`** created with client secret and **API permissions** successfully like below:

[image]

To do the same using **`Az`** module, you can run below powershell script:

```
# Connect to Azure Account
Connect-AzAccount -Tenant <TenantID>

# Create app registration
$application = New-AzADApplication -DisplayName "AzDemoApp" -ReplyUrls "https://jwt.ms"

# Create client secret
New-AzADAppCredential -ApplicationId $application.AppId -EndDate (Get-Date).AddYears(1) 

# Add User.Read.All Application permission
Add-AzADAppPermission -ApplicationId $application.AppId -ApiId "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000" -PermissionId "df021288-bdef-4463-88db-98f22de89214" -Type Role

# Add User.Read Delegated permission
Add-AzADAppPermission -ApplicationId $application.AppId -ApiId "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000" -PermissionId "e1fe6dd8-ba31-4d61-89e7-88639da4683d"
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I checked the same in Portal, new application named **`AzDemoApp`** created with client secret and **API permissions** successfully like below:

[image]

To get the **values** of **`-PermissionId`** for different API permissions, run below PowerShell commands:

For **Application** Permissions:

```
$MSGraph = Get-AzADServicePrincipal -All $true | ? { $_.DisplayName -eq "Microsoft Graph" }
$MSGraph.AppRole | FT ID, Value
```

For **Delegated** Permissions:

```
$MSGraph = Get-AzADServicePrincipal -All $true | ? { $_.DisplayName -eq "Microsoft Graph" }
$MSGraph.Oauth2PermissionScope | FT ID, Value
```